# is it possible to return just 2 values from an sql query?

Tags: php, mysql

is it possible to return 2 values from this?

I want that HAVING clause have maximum of two.

```
$sql = mysql_query("
SELECT *
FROM 
    `Bill`
WHERE
    ID_Number='12345'
HAVING 
    max(`Pay_Date`)
ORDER BY
    `Pay_Date`
 DESC LIMIT 2");
```

Comment: What if you just remove the `HAVING` clause?

Comment: You are using the ID_Number and max('pay_date'), how can u expect to return two values by using max('Pay_Date'). There can only be one maximum value

Comment: sorry but I need it.what I want is having maximum of 2 Pay_dates.

Comment: try describing it, the database structure you are using.

Comment: @BillHunter: Removing the `HAVING` clause.  Your `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` will give you the top 2 values.

Comment: I have foreign key ID_Number and I want to filter the Bill where Pay_Date having two latest date.

Comment: but I need to have only 2 or less coz I have if($num_rows=0){action}elseif($num_rows=1){action}elseif($num_rows=2){action}

Comment: hehehehe.sorry I forgot that I have LIMIT 2.sorry for disturbance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can order the result by pay_date instead.

```
$sql = mysql_query("
SELECT *
FROM 
    `Bill`
WHERE
    ID_Number='12345'
ORDER BY
    `Pay_Date`
 DESC LIMIT 2");
```

This should work because you will be ordering the results by pay_date in desc. order. So the latest two dates will be displayed.

Comment: This is correct but I have mysql_num_rows and need to filter rows into two or less.

Comment: try describing your answer in full. Its very difficult to understand your question,.

Comment: I need to have only 2 or less rows coz I have "if($num_rows=0){action}elseif($num_rows=1){action}elseif($num_rows=2){action}"

Comment: By it's definition `Limit 2` can only ever return a maximum of 2 results? So I'm not sure what you are trying to ask?

Comment: Yes.. Limit 2 is meant for returning two results and your $num_rows will be 2, so whats the problem??

Comment: ya.. enjoy programming.. enjoy the web dude :) and ultimately enjoy stackoverflow .